# Как вызвать SharedPreferences в произвольном классе

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Есть виджет для Андроида. Суть его работы: парсить `JSON` с сайта и выводить некоторые данные. Виджет имеет активность, через которую при установке виджета можно вбить пользовательские данные и сохранить их в `Shared Preferences`.

Нижеприведенный код позволяют вызвать значение Preferences в клаcсе самого Виджета. Но мне нужно, чтобы это значение передавалось в класс `HTTPRequestThread2` (его мы вызываем из виджета) который обращается к JSON сайта.

Вот код самого виджета.

```
public class NHwidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
private static final String SYNC_CLICKED    = "nhwidget_update_action";
private static final String WAITING_MESSAGE = "Обновляем";
private static final String NOCONNECTING_MESSAGE = "Нет\nподключения";
public static final int httpsDelayMs = 300;

static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                            int appWidgetId) {

    CharSequence widgetText = NHwidgetConfigureActivity.loadTitlePref(context, appWidgetId);
    // Construct the RemoteViews object
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.nhwidget);
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, widgetText);

    // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

    String output2;
    // Запускаем отдельный поток для получения данных с сайта
    HTTPRequestThread2 thread2 = new HTTPRequestThread2();
    thread2.start();
    try {
        while (true) {
            Thread.sleep(300);
            if(!thread2.isAlive()) {
                output2 = thread2.getInfoString();
                break;
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        output2 = "";
    }

    //выводим в виджет результат
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text_balance, output2);
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // When the user deletes the widget, delete the preference associated with it.
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        NHwidgetConfigureActivity.deleteTitlePref(context, appWidgetId);
    }
}

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
}
}
```

Код Активности для сохранения введенных значений в Preferences:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class NHwidgetConfigureActivity extends Activity {

private static final String PREFS_NAME = "com.test.nhmonitor.NHwidget";
private static final String PREF_PREFIX_KEY = "appwidget_";
int mAppWidgetId = AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID;
EditText mAppWidgetText;
View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final Context context = NHwidgetConfigureActivity.this;

        // When the button is clicked, store the string locally
        String widgetText = mAppWidgetText.getText().toString();
        saveTitlePref(context, mAppWidgetId, widgetText);

        // It is the responsibility of the configuration activity to update the app widget
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        NHwidget.updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, mAppWidgetId);

        // Make sure we pass back the original appWidgetId
        Intent resultValue = new Intent();
        resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
        finish();
    }
};

public NHwidgetConfigureActivity() {
    super();
}

// Write the prefix to the SharedPreferences object for this widget
static void saveTitlePref(Context context, int appWidgetId, String text) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0).edit();
    prefs.putString(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId, text);
    prefs.apply();
}

// Read the prefix from the SharedPreferences object for this widget.
// If there is no preference saved, get the default from a resource
static String loadTitlePref(Context context, int appWidgetId) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    String titleValue = prefs.getString(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId, null);
    if (titleValue != null) {
        return titleValue;
    } else {
        return context.getString(R.string.appwidget_text);
    }
}

static void deleteTitlePref(Context context, int appWidgetId) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0).edit();
    prefs.remove(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId);
    prefs.apply();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    // Set the result to CANCELED.  This will cause the widget host to cancel
    // out of the widget placement if the user presses the back button.
    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);

    setContentView(R.layout.nhwidget_configure);
    mAppWidgetText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.appwidget_text);
    findViewById(R.id.add_button).setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);

    // Find the widget id from the intent.
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        mAppWidgetId = extras.getInt(
                AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    }

    // If this activity was started with an intent without an app widget ID, finish with an error.
    if (mAppWidgetId == AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
        finish();
        return;
    }

    mAppWidgetText.setText(loadTitlePref(NHwidgetConfigureActivity.this, mAppWidgetId));
}
}
```

Код класса, где выполняется запрос к URL и где нужно получить сохраненное значение из Preferences:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

class HTTPRequestThread2 extends Thread{

private static final String urlString = "https://btc-e.nz/api/3/ticker/";

String getInfoString() {
    return output2;
}

private String output2 = "";

private void requestPrice() {

    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        output2 = JSONParser.getPrice(response.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        output2 = "";
    }

}

@Override
public void run() {
    requestPrice();
}

}
```

Comment: Ну а что, через конструктор этого класса при создании экземпляра нельзя что ли передать все, что угодно? и зачем вам читать из преференсов в каком то классе, если в виджете, откуда вы вызываете этот класс уже есть полученное значение, почему не передавать его?

Comment: @pavlofff, возможно так и проще. Я даже пытался повторить в классе HTTPRequestThread2 строку вызова значения в переменную CharSequence widgetText = NHwidgetConfigureActivity.loadTitlePref(context, appWidgetId); Вся проблема в том, что я не понимаю, почему это не работает.